# How to generate .ics file using PHP for a given date range and time

Tags: php, icalendar

I am trying to find an effective method to generate a downloadable ".ics" file using PHP, based on a given date range (start date - end date) and reminder time.

Could any one provide me a sample PHP code to create this feature.

Comment: Welcome to SO, questions just looking for something like a tutorial or code without showing own efforts (e.g. what's your current implementation, why isn't it fitting) are normally considered off-topic and will get closed and then deleted.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20120419230026/http://jamiebicknell.tumblr.com/post/413492676/ics-generator-php-class

**Note:** original blog post is gone; preserving with arhcive.org link.

---

Copy and paste the information of the above link:

```
<?php
class ICS {
    var $data;
    var $name;
    function ICS($start,$end,$name,$description,$location) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->data = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($start))."\nDTEND:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($end))."\nLOCATION:".$location."\nTRANSP: OPAQUE\nSEQUENCE:0\nUID:\nDTSTAMP:".date("Ymd\THis\Z")."\nSUMMARY:".$name."\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\nPRIORITY:1\nCLASS:PUBLIC\nBEGIN:VALARM\nTRIGGER:-PT10080M\nACTION:DISPLAY\nDESCRIPTION:Reminder\nEND:VALARM\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR\n";
    }
    function save() {
        file_put_contents($this->name.".ics",$this->data);
    }
    function show() {
        header("Content-type:text/calendar");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->name.'.ics"');
        Header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->data));
        Header('Connection: close');
        echo $this->data;
    }
}
?>
```

Output the ICS file to the browser and give the user the option to open or save

```
<?php
$event = new ICS("2009-11-06 09:00","2009-11-06 21:00","Test Event","This is an event made by Jamie Bicknell","GU1 1AA");
$event->show();
?>
```

Save the ICS file onto the server in the current working directory

```
<?php
$event = new ICS("2009-11-06 09:00","2009-11-06 21:00","Test Event","This is an event made by Jamie Bicknell","GU1 1AA");
$event->save();
?>
```

Comment: Cannot access the page using this link:

Comment: who is the author of the code and under which licensing terms is it available? The website you linked does not work any longer.

Comment: For me the site works perfect, on the other hand this is the author http://www.twitter.com/jamiebicknell ask him.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old post, but I can't see how the section described as "Output the ICS file to the browser and give the user the option to open or save", allows the user to open or save.

Comment: Using other non-maintained resource is not a good solution...

Comment: @SteveIves the part of the header that says `Content-Disposition: attachment;` is what tells the browser it's a file download. That is what OP meant by "allows the user to open or save". I also updated the answer with a link to an archive.org snapshot of the blog post, since it's gone now.