# How to export data in a ics file?

Tags: php, icalendar

I found this solution for a single event: [How to generate .ics file using PHP for a given date range and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739247/how-to-generate-ics-file-using-php-for-a-given-date-range-and-time) but I need to export multiple events in a single file.

I'm not really sure what I should update in the given class, can you please show me some direction in what should be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really hate the very old PHP code from the link you provide, but try this update:

```php
<?php
class ICS {
    var $data = "";
    var $name;
    var $start = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\n";
    var $end = "END:VCALENDAR\n";
    function ICS($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    function add($start,$end,$name,$description,$location) {
        $this->data .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($start))."\nDTEND:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($end))."\nLOCATION:".$location."\nTRANSP: OPAQUE\nSEQUENCE:0\nUID:\nDTSTAMP:".date("Ymd\THis\Z")."\nSUMMARY:".$name."\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\nPRIORITY:1\nCLASS:PUBLIC\nBEGIN:VALARM\nTRIGGER:-PT10080M\nACTION:DISPLAY\nDESCRIPTION:Reminder\nEND:VALARM\nEND:VEVENT\n";
    }
    function save() {
        file_put_contents($this->name.".ics",$this->getData());
    }
    function show() {
        header("Content-type:text/calendar");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$this->name.'.ics"');
        Header('Content-Length: '.strlen($this->getData()));
        Header('Connection: close');
        echo $this->getData();
    }
    function getData() {
        return $this->start . $this->data . $this->end;
    }
}
?>
```

And use it like that:

```php
<?php
$event = new ICS("Test");
$event->add("2009-11-06 09:00","2009-11-06 21:00","Test Event1","This is an event 1","GU1 1AA");
$event->add("2010-11-06 09:00","2010-11-06 21:00","Test Event2","This is an event 2","GU1 1AA");
$event->save(); // $event->show();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :)