# Integrating an ICS file link in the output email of Contact Form 7 Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to build an ICS file link using user input to my ContactForm7 form and then include this ICS file link in the email output of the form to my inbox.

NB: an ICS file is a link that can be read by Outlook, Google Calendar, Apple Calendar etc...

```
    // build an ICS file using this class
    class ICS {
        var $data;
        var $name;

        function ICS($start,$end,$name,$description,$location) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->data = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($start))."\nDTEND:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime($end))."\nLOC\
    ATION:".$location."\nTRANSP: OPAQUE\nSEQUENCE:0\nUID:\nDTSTAMP:".date("Ymd\THis\Z")."\nSUMMARY:".$name."\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\nPRIORITY:1\nCLASS:PUBLIC\nBEGIN:VALARM\nTRIGGE\
    R:-PT10080M\nACTION:DISPLAY\nDESCRIPTION:Reminder\nEND:VALARM\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR\n";
        }
        function save() {
            file_put_contents($this->name.".ics",$this->data);
        }
        function show() {                                                                               
            return $this->data;
        }
    }

    // add action before_send_mail
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'before_send_mail' );

    // build the ICS file here and include it in the email to my inbox
    function before_send_mail( $wpcf7 ) {

        private $ics_link;

        // call the ICS class instance
        $event = new ICS("2023-03-30 16:00","2023-03-30 17:00","Test Event","This an event made to test","GU1 1AA");
        
        // Add the ICS file string
        $ics_link = $event->show();

        // CAPTURE INSTANCE OF WPCFY CLASS AND ADD ICS FILE LINK TO EMAIL BODY 
        


    }
```

NNB: I got most of the ICS file class from this StackOverflow page..

[How to generate .ics file using PHP for a given date range and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739247/how-to-generate-ics-file-using-php-for-a-given-date-range-and-time)

Comment: I guess what i'm asking guys, since the WordPress Contact Form 7 is referenced as an object before sending the email based on the Contact Form. How do i add a .ics file link to that object? Eg. "function before_send_email( $wpcf7 )", how do i override this $wpcf7 object and to it? Obviously i can't alter the plugin code or core. Has to be done in theme/functions.php.

Comment: this is the wrong filter you're looking at.  Instead you need to look at the `wpcf7_mail_components` hook and filter the `$components['attachment']` to include your generated ICS file.

Answer (score 0):

> this is the wrong filter you're looking at. Instead you need to look
> at the wpcf7_mail_components hook and filter
> the $components['attachment'] to include your generated ICS file.

This was the answer written by [@Aurovrata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3596672/aurovrata) in the comments.